# Таймер обратного отсчета идет в минус

Tags: javascript

Как сделать так что бы после истечения счетчика он начинал заново считать время?

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 1 * 1 * 1 * 60 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

```html
<div class="timer">
     <div id="clockdiv" class="tmcontainer">
      <div class="days-c">
       <span class="days pl5"></span>
       <small>&nbsp;дней</small>
      </div>
      <div class="hours-c">
       <span class="hours"></span>
       <small>часов</small>
      </div>
      <div class="minutes-c">
       <span class="minutes"></span>
       <small>минут</small>
      </div>
      <div class="seconds-c">
       <span class="seconds pr5"></span>
       <small class="pr5">секунд</small>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: а откуда взялось `Date.parse(new Date))`? в чем смысл?

Comment: Уже поднимался этот вопрос не раз. Вынесите переменную `timeinterval` в глобальный *scope*, т.е. за пределы функции `initializeClock`.

Comment: @RomanMaksimov эммм, зачем?

Comment: @akasergej, просто вместо того, что бы останавливать таймер `clearInterval(timeinterval);` по истечении времени, установите значение переменной endtime на новое время и таймер пойдет считать дальше.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло